# Rectangle object using two-dimensional array

Tags: java, arrays, applet

If i have a two-dimensional array, is it possible to print out the result as a rectangle?

Here is what i have come up with;

```
int[][] anArrayRectangle = {{0,0},{-2,0},{1,-2},
                            {0,1},{2,1},{2,0}};
```

Each point represents one out of six points which together create a rectangle in the unit circle.
The question is if it is possible to display the rectangle in lines, not exclusively using the print method. Perhaps in an applet?

All tips are welcome.

Comment: How are you representing your rectangle?  Usually, a rectangle is simply two points - either a corner and with/height or two opposite corners.  Your points aren't even on the borders of a single rectangle.  Is the rectangle the smallest rectangle that contains all the points?

Comment: For display purposes, you're (probably) going to want to use the stuff in `java.awt.geom`.  Although this smells a bit like homework.

Comment: In addition to the points @Retief makes, several of your points are *outside* the unit circle, so how do they "create a rectangle in the unit circle"?

Comment: @Retief: Two opposite corners only define a rectangle, if you know the angle, for example if the lines are all horizontal or vertical.

Comment: *"Perhaps in an applet?"*  (Almost) Anything that can be done in an applet can be done in a desktop app.  Certainly this can.  Since applets are an order of magnitude more tricky than desktop apps., use the desktop app.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use drawPolygon

---

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Rectangle extends JPanel {

private int xPos[] = {100, 150, 200, 200, 150, 100};
private int yPos[] = {100, 100, 100, 150, 150, 150};

public void paint(Graphics g) {

    super.paint(g);

    int length = xPos.length;

    g.drawPolygon(xPos, yPos, length);

}

private static JFrame frame = null;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    frame = new JFrame("Graphics");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(400, 400);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    Rectangle obj = new Rectangle();

    frame.add(obj);

}
```

}

[image]